# Get subclass content from object

Tags: c#

I have the following classes

```
public enum Category { foo, foo1, foo2 }

public class Event
{

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string GameTime { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Person Author { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class MemberEvent : Event
{
    public Member Person { get; set; }                
}
```

The object is created correctly, but if I want to call "Person", this is not displayed to me. If I have a `var match`, I can call for example `match[0].Timestamp` but not `match[0].Person`. The `Event` object is stored in a `List`, therefore also the index. I feel I'm missing something simple.

UPDATE: The Code that create the Object

```
var match = SessionController.Instance.Current;

DataTable dt = dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataTable;

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
                var memberFoo = new MemberEvent();
                memberFoo.Category = Category.Warning;
                memberFoo.Time = item["Time"].ToString();
                var person = new Person();
                person.FirstName = item["FirstName"].ToString();
                person.LastName = item["LastName"].ToString();
                var passport = new Passport();
                passport.Active = true;
                passport.PassNumber = item["Pass"].ToString();
                passport.Player = person;
                memberFoo.Person = passport;
                match.Match.Events.Add(memberFoo);             
        }

        SessionController.Instance.Current = match;
```

Comment: Is the list for `Event` ? If the list is created as `List<Event>`, it would not be possible to find the property `Person`, since it is not a `MemberEvent`.

Comment: Can you post the actual code where you are creating the objects?  That will greatly help.

Comment: @EtienneFaucher yes it is created as `List<Event>`

Comment: You will have to cast your instances to your `MemberEvent` to get the `Person` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your instance to the expected type and test for null to guard for the unexpected:

```
var memberEvent = match[0] as MemberEvent;
if (memberEvent != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(memberEvent.Person)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Actually it's very simple but sometimes I'm too blind :D

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cast your `Event` into a `MemberEvent` if you want to access the `Person` property. It is not possible to get the property from `Event`.

```
List<Event> myEvents = GetMyEvents();
var myMemberEvent = (MemberEvent)myEvent[0];
```

It can cause an exception if it can't convert to `MemberEvent`.